How to clear cart automatically when users and visitors leave the checkout page?
I got this code to clear cart and it's working perfectly for logged-in users but not guests. For guests, I have to leave the checkout page and load another page to clear the cart.
How to auto empty cart when leaving checkout for registered customers and guest?
This is the code (picked from stack overflow):
<?php

//we inserted a script in wordpress and put it in the head
add_action('wp_head', 'woocommerce_clear_cart_url');
function woocommerce_clear_cart_url()
{
   global $woocommerce;
   //we used the jquery beforeunload function to detect if the user leaves that page
?>
   <script>
      jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
         $(window).bind('beforeunload', function() {
            //Used WordPress to help jQuery determine the page we're targeting 
            //pageID is the page number of the page we're targeting
            <?php if (!is_page(pageID)):
               //empty the cart
               $woocommerce->cart->empty_cart(); ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
         });
      });
   </script>
<?php } ?>


The use of the beforeunload handler there makes no sense to begin with. The PHP code you put inside that JavaScript function, executes on the server side, when this script / page gets requested. And since the PHP code doesn't produce any output, you have simply created any "empty" JS function there to be executed, when the user leaves the page.

For this you can try it by pure php code. In this you would required template_redirect hook.
Add below code in function.php
<?php

add_filter('template_redirect', function () {
   if (!is_checkout() && !WC()->cart->is_empty()) {
      WC()->cart->empty_cart();
   }
   if (is_cart() && WC()->cart->is_empty()) {
      wp_redirect(home_url());
      exit;
   }
   if (is_cart() && !WC()->cart->is_empty()) {
      wp_redirect(wc_get_checkout_url());
      exit;
   }
});

Note: Please ensure you have done fast checkout once product gets added to cart directly send them to checkout page. So this could make more sence.

@LoicTheAztec Thanks for info. Same type of code I have implemented in my recent project. So added it. Also that code have another functions for if user try to open cart then redirected to shop if cart empty if not then to checkout updating full code.

Your code empty the cart when adding a product… So it doesn't allow the customer to add a product.

It is like if user will set quantity and clicked on Add to Cart  it will take you directly to checkout screen if you reload checkout no issue if you go to another page it will clear cart.
Same thing I have implemented for bookings.

Tested: Your code doesn't work, the customer can't keep a single product in cart before reaching checkout… It empties the cart everywhere except on checkout.

When click on add to cart please click on checkout page it will work
